# Discern contextmenu events which are result of touch action?

Tags: javascript, html, touch, contextmenu, dom-events

I have an application where elements inside of a SVG element can be drag and dropped (thanks to [d3-drag](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag) and [d3-zoom](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom), see https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3127661b6f13f9316be745e77fdfb084 as an example for such a page) which can be also used on touch-enabled devices but what happens is that after a long press a context menu pops up (at least in IE11, Edge and Firefox) and is in the way, therefore I want to prevent the context menu from showing up in this case.

I could just disallow showing the context menu in general by handling the `contextmenu` event and doing `.preventDefault()` on the event object but I wonder whether a solution exists where the context menu is just blocked from showing in the touch case and it would still show up for e.g. right-clicks or when the [menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) is pressed while the element has focus.

I thought at first I could look at the `.button` and `.buttons` properties of the event object but it seems like those values are arbitrarily `0` or `2` and it looks like it can be found in any combination when testing in various browsers on different systems.

The element already has `touch-action: none`.

**Is there some working way to make the context menu just not show up a result of a touch long-presses?**

[It looks like `.preventDefault()` on the relevant touch events wouldn't be an option.](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/issues/9)

Comment: I think you could turn the touch-actions back on and use `touchmove` and `touchend` events to determine whether or not to open the contextMenu. For example: on a `touchmove` you could set a flag that long-presses should be ignored. then on `touchend` you could turn the flag off. in the `contextmenu` event handler just check the flag. does that make sense?

Comment: @Potter Sounds promising but I would have to try that out in detail, e.g. whether there wouldn't be any race conditions, e.g. whether the `contextmenu` event truly is only triggered after the relevant touch events on all browsers and platforms. I just learned that even in the mouse case there are differences where on some systems it's the press of the right mouse button which triggers the context menu while on others it's the release.

Comment: @Potter Also, theoretically I could be dealing with users who are on convertibles and therefore mixing things up but I guess at that is such an edge case that it's not worth worrying about. I am beginning to think that maybe just preventing all `contextmenu` events isn't so bad after all, your average user isn't using it much and if then only on links for which I guess I could allow it again. What does get lost are features like e.g. in Edge you can right-click on an SVG (even dynamically generated ones) and download it but in my case it's broken anyway (because of CSS and ext. refs).

Answer (score -1):

jQuery UI Touch Punch just solves it all.

It's a Touch Event Support for jQuery UI. Basically, it just wires touch event back to jQuery UI. Tested on iPad, iPhone, Android and other touch-enabled mobile devices. I used jQuery UI sortable and it works like a charm.

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: In my case `d3` is already doing all the touch event handling for me so I don't want another library. I am looking for a low-level solution.

Comment: If it would work on https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3127661b6f13f9316be745e77fdfb084 (in all browser/OS combinations) then it would probably work in my application as well.